# python pulp not matching value of variable dict

Tags: python, pulp

I am struggling to simplify the constraint for a few days now.  still learning python.  please help and thank you in advance.

```
    Employees=['Paul', 'Ben', 'Nasim', 'Ceci', 'Victoria',]
    Days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',      
    'Saturday', 'Sunday']

    avail = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("on_off", ((employee, day) for     
    employee in Employees for day in Days), cat="Binary")

    requests={"Paul": {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":1,   
    "Thursday":1, "Friday":1, "Saturday":1, "Sunday":1},
    "Ben": {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":1, "Thursday":1, 
    "Friday":1, "Saturday":1, "Sunday":0},
    "Nasim": {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":1, "Thursday":1, 
    "Friday":1, "Saturday":1, "Sunday":1},
    "Ceci": {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":1, "Thursday":1, 
    "Friday":1,"Saturday":1, "Sunday":0},
    "Victoria": {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":0, "Thursday":0, 
    "Friday":0, "Saturday":0, "Sunday":0}}



    for employee, day in avail:
            prob += avail[employee, day] == [requests[i][j] for i in    
            requests for j in requests[i]]
```

as an example, the first few constraints:

```
"_C13: on_off_('Paul',_'Monday') = 28
_C14: on_off_('Paul',_'Tuesday') = 28
_C15: on_off_('Paul',_'Wednesday') = 28
_C16: on_off_('Paul',_'Thursday') = 28
_C17: on_off_('Paul',_'Friday') = 28
_C18: on_off_('Paul',_'Saturday') = 28"
```

("28" is just so happened to be the SUM of all the 1's and the 0's in my nested dict.)

Instead i like to have each variable matching 1's and 0's from my nested dict.

```
"_C13: on_off_('Paul',_'Monday') = 1
_C14: on_off_('Paul',_'Tuesday') = 1
_C15: on_off_('Paul',_'Wednesday') = 1
_C16: on_off_('Paul',_'Thursday') = 1
_C17: on_off_('Paul',_'Friday') = 1
_C18: on_off_('Paul',_'Saturday') = 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the == sign you want the value 1 or 0 from the dictionary, therefore you should use:

```
for employee, day in avail:
    prob += avail[employee, day] == requests[employee][day]
```

With requests[employee] you select the dictionary for that employee

```
requests['Paul'] = {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":1, "Wednesday":1,   
"Thursday":1, "Friday":1, "Saturday":1, "Sunday":1}
```

Then by adding [day] you select the day from that dictionary:

```
 requests['Paul']['Monday'] = 1
```

Comment: Would be great if you didn't just write some code as an answer. What is your thinking behind this code, how does it solve the question efficiently?

Comment: Programming is about *understanding*. Please provide context to your answer

Comment: @user3053215 thanks very much for the help.  it worked.  I was trying different ideas like zip(), chain map, and different comprehensions ideas.  the parts that confuse me was the how does python know that "employee" in requests (right side) is the same "employee" in avail (left side)?  I would assume they both have the same # of position so python automatically matches each other.  Also, why we don't need a for loop to load up the requests on the right side of the equal sign?  thanks again.

Comment: @fishtang Employee is a variable defined in the scope of the for loop, so it has the same everywhere during the loop. You don't need a loop because you just want one value on the right side, not multiple. Also, can you accept the answer if it worked for you?